# Database views and models being called in my controller

Tags: sql-server, cakephp

I am a little new to cakephp 3 and i am trying to figure out how you call this simple model/table in my index controller so that i can get the values to show up on my webpage.

this is my view vCalcTranscriptUpdateTerms in sql management

then this is my code for the model/table

due to it being a very very basic table of just 1 i only put 1 statemnt just to load the view.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class UpdatedTranscriptsTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setTable('preload.vCalcTranscriptUpdateTerms');
    }
}
```

now that i have a table set to that view how the heck do i call that table in my controller and get all of the information out of it?

Comment: A smart approach to this would be to simple read book.cakephp.org and do the tutorials there. They explain all the basics.

Answer (score 0):

at the top of controller include the below code for accessing the models

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

and you add the in before filter function or in initialize function 
or you can use it inside any function where you have indeed

$this->loadModel('UpdatedTranscripts');