# Calling a view in cakePHP

Tags: sql-server, cakephp

Lets say i have a result set in a sql management view like this

```
schoolYear    FiscalYear    updateTerm    whereTerm    Schools
2018-2019        2019            1            2        East,Memorial,West
```

My model table is written simple because there is only 1 data set right now and am changing the data through a stored procedure later on. so all i want is to view the information as it is currently in the database.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->setTable('vCalcTranscriptUpdateTerms');
}
```

and then in my controller index function i have this.

```
    $transcripts = TableRegistry::get('UpdatedTranscripts');

    $Transcript = $transcripts
    ->find()
    ->where(['FiscalYear' => 2018])
    ->first();

    debug($Transcript->title);
```

**Why is it that when i load my webpage it errors out and says Cannot describe vCalcTranscriptUpdateTerms "which is the sql view" and says it has 0 columns?** i am boggled as to how you can pull that sort of information in cakephp from a darn sql view. once i figure out ow to display it before i can do it after the procedure executes aswell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database views and models being called in my controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769395/database-views-and-models-being-called-in-my-controller)

Comment: What version of CakePHP 3 are you using? Supposedly limitations for Sql Server were ironed out in this PR a while ago https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7846